# Where is view controller for /login in messages-jc project?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

As it said in [tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/form.html):

> Within Spring Web MVC, the first step is to ensure that we have a
>   controller that can point to our view. Since our project adds the
>   **messages-jc** project as a dependency and it contains a view controller
>   for **/login** we do not need to create a controller within our
>   application

I've looked through its sources and didn't find any controller for `/login`. May be I missed something?

Here are links where I looked:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/messages-jc/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/samples/mvc

http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-samples-messages-jc/4.0.2.RELEASE/

Comment: check here
/spring-security-samples-messages-jc/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/samples/mvc/config/WebMvcConfiguration.java